# Create Mysql User that Can be Connect from any host

Tags: mysql, server

I want to create mysql user that can be connect from any host, i have followed instruction from MYSQL documentation from this link

[Adding User Accounts](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/adding-users.html)

MYSQL documentation said i should create two user with host localhost and %. So i create two user like documentation said. Give same grant privileges to both. And then execute flush privileges. All user work on localhost, but when i try to connect from other host, it always said Can't connect on MySQL server on ....

Any opinion ?

Comment: Creating a user that can connect from anywhere can be very dangerous. I wouldn't recommend it.